# sonarqube c# connected mode not analyzing new projects

Tags: c#, sonarqube, branch

I have created a new project in my solution but have not checked the solution onto the branch that connected mode is pointed to.  Is it not possible to get code analysis on this new project prior to checking the project/solution back onto the branch that connnected mode is pointed to?  I would like to be able to clean up code issues prior to checking the project into the branch.

Comment: Are you running on windows?

Comment: Yes, Win 10 64bit

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam - Good to know it is possible to run sonarqube on windows!  Maybe this user has an older version eh?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to see issues in SonarLint.

When SonarLint binds a solution (e.g. connects it to SonarQube) it adds references to the SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/VisualBasic nuget packages and disables its built-in code analyzers. When you add new project to a bound solution, the nuget package references are not automatically added and since the built-in analyzers in SonarLint are disabled, you don't see warnings. To add the nuget packages you need to update the bindings of the solution from the Team Explorer pane.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  Yes, I am trying to see issues via SonarLint.  Even after running the update from Team Explorer I am not seeing issues reflected via SonarLint on my desktop.  Specific issues were added in my code for connected mode test purposes.

Comment: @Ronbo71 do you have the analyzers from SonarAnalyzer.* nugets referenced in your project? They should be listed under References/Analyzers. 
Other way to check that is to open the csproj file and look for `<Analyzer Include="..." />` elements. Other possible reason for missing issues could be if some of the rules are disabled on SonarQube, but if the rules are disabled you should not be seeing issues in SonarQube as well.